# Calculate average size of bubbles on plenty of pictures

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have pictures like this: [image]

There are around 100 pictures, they differ from each other by diameters of black bubbles. I need to calculate the average diameter of bubbles on every picture. So, in the end, I am supposed to have an array of 100 elements.

General structure of the script should be:

```
number_of_picture = 1
for-loop (from first image to the last)
get(picture_number_of_picture);
turn rgb image to binary one;
calculate average raw of bubbles;
number_of_picture = number_of_picture + 1;
end-loop
```

I have done all of this, so my script looks like:

```
i=317;
last = 415;

for photo=i:last;end;
    s1 = 'DSC_0';
    s2 = num2str(photo);
    s3 = '.JPG';
    s = strcat(strcat(s1,s2), s3)

%%  

img = imread(s);
imshow(img);
img = img(1:end, 1:end, 1);

%% intensity corection
scaled = img*1.90;

%imshow(scaled);
level = 120;
binary = scaled>level;


%% get binary
new_binary = binary(from_upper:end, from_left:to_right, 1);

%stats = regionprops(binary,'Area')
%   'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength');

imshow(binary);
%imshow(new_binary);
%s4 = 'new';
%s5 = strcat(s4, s);
%imwrite(new_binary,s5);
end
```

But I have troubles with diameter calculations. I thought that it is a standard task to get characteristics size of round objects, but none of the available solutions in the documentation does not fit.

For example function [regionprops()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) which come to mind does not give the proper result when I tried to execute it with parameter 'Perimeter', hoping to calculate diameters of bubbles by the perimeter, but the output is really odd.

Function [imfindcircles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html) assumes that you already know the average size of round objects, so it does help either.

Of course, there is a "solid" solution to run two for-loops and try to calculate sizes manually, but I cannot believe there is no built-in solution in Matlab for this.

Probably my problem is that I do not know all the possibilities of this language, but my quick analyze led me to the lock so I am asking.

What is the best approach to solving my problem?

**EDIT ONE**

Honestly, I do not quite understand function `regionprops()`. 
I am trying to get something essential at least on model example. Look< I take a picture from the doc:

[image]

And for this picture I executed this script:

```
 s = 'sample.jpg';
    img = imread(s);
    img = img(1:end, 1:end, 1);
    intensity = 1.00
    scaled = img*intensity;
    level = 20;
    binary = scaled>level;
    imshow(binary);
    stats = regionprops(binary,'EquivDiameter')
```

As far as I understand the World it should be only 3 diameters since there are three circles on it: 
But

`stats = [41.7347780298123, 
          81.7510511878280, 
          111.057964459329, 
          101.710723628205, 
          24.0955853300814]`

What's that?.. I do not get it

Comment: How about the `'EquivDiameter'` property instead?

Comment: Open your figure with a viewer that doesn't have a white background. There are two vertical white bands on the left and the right, those are your additional two regionprops which you can't account for.